# How to convert a semidefinite program to an optimization problem that can be solved by the ellipsoid method?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Suppose we have the following set of linear inequalities in $x \in \mathbb R^n$

$$\begin{aligned} a_1^T x &\leq b_1\\ a_2^T x &\leq b_2\\ &\vdots\\ a_k^T x &\leq b_k\end{aligned}$$

If the feasible set of these set of linear inequalities is a bounded full-dimensional set and contains a ball of radius $r > 0$ then the ellipsoid method finds a feasible point in polynomial time.

In some papers I have read that feasibility of every semidefinite program can be solved with the ellipsoid method.

My problem is that how we can convert the following form of a semidefinite programming to a set of inequalities (to be solved by the ellipsoid method)?

$$\text{s.t. }\langle A_{i},X \rangle=b_{i} , i=1,\ldots,m$$
$$X\succeq0$$

I will be grateful for every hint.

Comment: There isn't any finite system of linear inequalities that is equivalent to the feasible region of your SDP.  Rather, you'll need to find a separating hyperplane at each iteration of the ellipsoid algorithm.

Comment: Take a look at section 2.3 of [Linear Matrix Inequalities in System and Control Theory](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/lmibook/).